# How to access List elements in thymeleaf object

Tags: scala, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am passing list of objects to the view
like this:

```
model.addAttribute("checkForm",aa)
```

where aa looks like this: `List(object_1 address, object_2 address)`

now I want to access elements of this objects in HTML thymeleaf

```
<form method="post" th:each="check : ${checkForm}" th:action="${@r.check()}">
    <div th:each="aa : ${check}">
        <tbody valign="middle">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h5 th:text="${aa.title}"></h5>
                    <p th:text="${aa.details}"></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h4 class="price"><span th:text="${price}"></span></h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</form>
</tbody>
</div>
</form>
```

How can I access these values?

Comment: Why do you have nested `th:each`? Isn't `"checkForm"` only one-level deep list?
Can you also share error message you're getting?

Comment: 1st 'th:each' for to access every object in list and second one is for to access every element in object, i am getting this error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on object of type 'scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: Can you also edit your post and show what `object_1 address` and `object_2 address` is?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what object_1 or object_2 is, but I think you need an for adresses which has titel and details for beeing able to resolve the point operator

Comment: thanks everyone for the quick response, but i solve my problem now by changing the backend logic.thank you